# python create ligature substitution open type font

Tags: python-3.x, emoji, punycode

I tried to create python that makes a font which substitutes the string xn--e28h for the ligature  but im not sure Im going about this correctly. Id like to do this for the ~1150 fully qualified unicode 15 emoji that are single code point but just testing with the smiley face for now.

```
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
from fontTools.unicode import Unicode
from fontTools.varLib.builder import addOpenTypeLigature

# Create a new font
font = TTFont()

# Define ligature glyph data
ligature_name = "xn--e28h"
ligature_unicode = [0x1F604]  # Unicode code point for the smiley face emoji

# Create a ligature glyph
ligature_glyph = font.getGlyphSet().get(ligature_name)
ligature_glyph.width = 1000

# Update cmap and GSUB tables
font["cmap"].tables[0].addMapping(Unicode(*ligature_unicode), ligature_name)

# Create a GSUB lookup for ligature substitution
gsub_table = font.getGSUB()
lookup = gsub_table.table.LookupList.Lookup[0]  # Replace with the appropriate lookup index
addOpenTypeLigature(lookup, ligature_name, ['x', 'n', '-', '-', 'e', '2', '8', 'h'])

# Save the font
font.save("custom_font.otf")
```

script errors:
`line 3, in <module> from fontTools.varLib.builder import addOpenTypeLigature ImportError: cannot import name 'addOpenTypeLigature' from 'fontTools.varLib.builder' (/usr/local/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/fontTools/varLib/builder.py)`